# Is it a bad idea to use pagination based on jQuery because the site loads all the information at once anyways?

Tags: jquery, pagination

For intance, lets say we have 50 posts in a blog.
With php you would usually load 10 posts per page and the site will only load those 10 posts until you click another pagination page. Now with jQuery, the site will first load the 50 posts. Then jQuery will work with the generated HTML in order to build the pagination. Well, this is just an assumption; if there are a lot of posts, the performance will be highly affected (it will take a long time for the site to load at the beginning). I would like to know what if anyone had any experience using a jQuery-based pagination system.

Comment: You can use Ajax to load the next 10 posts and display them after they're loaded.

Comment: Why not compromise? Use one script to get the first page of data, then display it, then use AJAX to get all the data and cache it. You're only hitting the server twice, and the user doesn't perceive any delay between pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for jQuery pagination is to use a ajax json to asynchronously get the data results based upon request. This allows you to only load a small amount of the total data and still not have to reload the whole page when changing the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you load a lot of content every time a page is requested this will impact the server load and server performance, ie your site will run the risk of being very slow and not being able to handle many users.

There's a middle ground, however. You can still load only the first 10 posts when the page is requested, and then use jQuery to load additional posts with AJAX. The server load remains roughly the same as with a complete page reload and the user experience roughly the same as loading everything in one go (once it's all loaded).

Comment: Yeah - your answer hadn't appeared on my screen when I posted that.